# Preparing Mysqli Select Using Explode

Tags: php, loops, mysqli, foreach

Here I Explode the Above String with `,` and got the Array $myArray.

```
<?php
$myString = '1,2,3,4';
$myArray = explode(',', $myString);
print_r($myArray);
```

But How can i make it a select statement

```
mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Persons where id = 'First part of Array'");
mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Persons where id = 'Second part of Array'");
mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Persons where id = 'Third part of Array'"); ..
```

In Foreach Loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to Explode. check in where case  using `IN` operator

```
mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Persons where id IN (".$myString.")");
```

**query  like**

```
 SELECT * FROM Persons where id IN (1,2,3,4);
```

Answer (score 1):

why writing multiple sqls if you got the **IN** operator with you:

```
$myArray = explode(',', $myString);
```

if you have some specific need of string values then use this:

```
$myArray =array_map('strval', $myArray );

mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Persons where id IN (".$myString.")");
```

Answer (score 1):

I think its a bad idea to make a query for every iteration. Instead run a single query like

```
$myString = '1,2,3,4';
$myArray = explode(',', $myString);
  // Just format the string so that it appears as  '1','2'... instead of  '1,2'
for ($i = 0; $i < count($myArray); $i ++)
{
   $myArray[$i] = "'" . $myArray[$i] . "'";
}
$myFormattedString = implode(',', $myArray);

mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Persons where id IN (".$myFormattedString.")");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either use:

```
mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Persons where IN ('".$myString."')");
```

Or:

```
$ids = join(',',$myArray); 
mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Persons where IN ($ids)");
```